# Pius XII denied beatification of "a very well known founder of a religious order"?

Tags: catholicism, pius-xii, beatification

Sr. [Pascalina Lehnert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascalina_Lehnert), Pope [Pius XII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Pius_XII)'s housekeeper and secretary, wrote in [*His Humble Servant*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8658) ch. 11:

> One example was the beatification process of a very well known founder of a religious order. The proceedings were concluded and waiting for the Pope’s decision. On looking through the documents Pius XII now found some most distasteful words often used by the servant of God, which, however, were in general use in the region where they had been uttered and not regarded as objectionable, as he was assured from various quarters. Pius XII remained deaf to every request and representation. “I cannot,” he said simply. Although all the preparations had already been made, the beatification did not receive the “*Placet Eugenio*.”

Who was this "[servant of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_of_God#Catholic_Church)" and "very well known founder of a religious order"?

Comment: Josemaría Escriva died seventeen years after Pius XII.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Should your last sentence ask: Who was this **”venerable”** and "very well known founder” seeing that the question is about the promotion to beatification? Servant of God  is possibly a literary expression here?